# ASP.NET Project not Deploying on Google Cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-platform

I really need some help. It is driving me crazy and I don't know why it is not working.

Basically I am just trying to deploy my project to Google Cloud, but the process is bringing me an error and I can't understand why. The error below:

> MSDeployPublish:   Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to
>   https://35.238.89.74:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=MySite...   Starting Web
>   deployment task from source:
>   manifest(\MySiteFolder\obj\Release\Package\UANL.SourceManifest.xml) to
>   Destination: auto(). C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4292,5):
>   msdeploy error ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC: Web deployment
>   task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer
>   ("35.238.89.74") using the specified process ("Web Management
>   Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the
>   process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer. 
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)
>   [\MySiteFolder\MySite.csproj]   Publish failed to deploy. Done
>   Building Project "\MySiteFolder\MySite.csproj" (WebPublish target(s))
>   -- FAILED.

It is something that I can't do anything (I guess) because it is inside Google Cloud application.

I saw something related to Firewall but I checked everything and seems to be fine. I don't if I am right, but if it is the problem, please give me a step by step, because it is so confusing.

Thanks in advance for you help!!

Comment: is it ASP.NET Core?

Comment: is web deploy enabled on the cloud? is it a VM or? Is it running IIS? do you have full control over the web server?

Comment: it is ASP.NET MVC... I instantiated an image that has all I need, I suppose.. the IIS, SQL Server Express and .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: have you tried this one?: https://www.benday.com/2013/07/12/fix-error_could_not_connect_to_remotesvc-error-using-visual-studio-2012-web-deploy/

Comment: Hello @AlisonVieira were you able to get a solution to this? I'm facing similar trouble, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error `ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC` cost me two days to figure out that for my case, the site name didn't match. The site name on the remote IIS server was different from the site name i had set in visual Studio for the deployment